# Select all rows from last inserted

Tags: mysql

What I'd like to do is retrieve ALL the posts that have the last time inserted. So:

```
time_of_insertion | content
        x              --
       x+1             --
       x+1             --
       x+1             --
       x+2             --
       x+2             --      
       x+2             --
       x+2             --
```

What I'd like to do is  obtain the last two posts with `x+2` because they both are the last inserted. Can this be done? Thank you very much...

EDIT: sorry guys I forgot to mention I wanted this on an union

Supposing I want the MAX(last time_of_insertion) from two different tables. So if table1 has x+1 time of insertion and table2 has x+3, I want x+3 from table2, not table1. Any ideas?

Comment: Bit ugly, but it should work... there likely is a more efficient way...`Select * 
from 
(Select time from table1 
union all 
 select time from table2) B
WHERE time = (Select max(time) from (Select time from table1 union all select time from table2)`

Comment: @xQbert you are missing one ')', but anyway it gives me `Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: @xQbert `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'b) c' at line 1`. I tried changing the parenthesis, nothing happened

Comment: Realized I had alias in wrong place: after reformatting... perhaps `SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT TIME FROM table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME FROM table2
  ) B
WHERE TIME =
  (SELECT MAX(TIME)
  FROM
    (SELECT TIME FROM table1
    union all
    SELECT TIME FROM table2) a)`

Comment: @xQbert OHHHHHHHHHHHHHH YES BABY THIS IS WHAT I'M TALKING ABOUT, OHHHHHHHHH YES BABY, HIGH FIVE; HIGH FIVE PUT THAT SH;* AS AN ANSWER TO GIVE YOU CREDIT MA BABY BOY

Comment: heh... no need to be sooo excited :P  Just glad we could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several formatting errors and incorrect / missing inline table aliases...

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT TIME 
  FROM table1 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT TIME 
  FROM table2 
  ) B 
WHERE TIME = (
  SELECT MAX(TIME) 
  FROM (
    SELECT TIME 
    FROM table1 
    union all 
    SELECT TIME 
    FROM table2) a
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just query the max time and then pick every post matching.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE time_of_insertion = (SELECT MAX(time_of_insertion) FROM table);
```

Comment: How can this be combined with an union? Supposing I want the MAX(last time_of_insertion) from two different tables. So if table1 has x+1 time of insertion and table2 has x+3, I want x+3 from table2, not table1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all you need to do is retrieve the max time_of_insertion and use it in your where like this:

```
select * from table where time_of_insertion = (SELECT MAX(time_of_insertion) from table) ;
```

Comment: How can this be combined with an union? Supposing I want the MAX(last time_of_insertion) from two different tables. So if table1 has x+1 time of insertion and table2 has x+3, I want x+3 from table2, not table1. Any ideas?